# Difficulty in understanding Petersons Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, mutex

I am having a bit difficulty understanding the peterson's algorithm:
The algorithm says:

```
flag[i] = true;
turn = j;
while (flag[j] && turn == j);
// critical section
...
// end of critical section
flag[i] = false;
```

Now lets suppose initially
flag[0]=flag[1]=true

If P1 starts executing, it will be busy waiting at the while loop since flag[0] and turn==0 both will be true. Now if P0 does not want to execute, P1 will never execute the critical section.

Please clear my doubt;there may be gaps in my understanding.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Now lets suppose initially flag[0]=flag[1]=true
>
> Now if P0 does not want to execute, P1 will never execute the critical section.

Both flags should be initialized to `false`. The only way that both could be set to `true` is if both processes want to execute or are currently executing the critical section. Therefore if P1 is waiting to execute, `flag[0]` is `true`, so P0 must be either about to execute the critical section, or in the middle of executing it, after which `flag[0]` will be set to `false` and P1 can enter the critical section. Also, If P1 is waiting to execute, the P0 cannot be also waiting to execute, because the waiting conditions are mutually exclusive (since `turn` is either 0 or 1 and cannot be both simultaneously).

Initializing both flags to `true` can lead to a deadlock as you describe. Doing so makes no sense, since the meaning of the flags is to indicate that the process wants to enter the critical section, so if that's not the case, why set that value?

Comment: Thanks.  So it has to be initialized to false.

Comment: Yes, correct. Initializing both to true can lead to a deadlock.